# Why does it say that pygame is already installed but I can't use it

Tags: python, pygame

Why does it say that `pygame` is already installed, but when I type `import pygame` in my code, it says that `pygame` is not recognized.
*I've tried many ways online but none of them worked.*

I've tried reinstalling `pygame`, reinstalling `python`, and a lot of ways on the `Internet`, but so far no good.

Comment: So, what says that `pygame` is already installed?

Comment: It says pygame is already installed when I try `pip install pygame`.

Comment: Ok, but where did `pip` put that library? Which version of python do you use? And where is that installed?

Comment: Does the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378229/pip-install-package-installed-but-python-is-not-importing) help at all?

Comment: you might have  to use `pip3 install pygame`

Comment: `pip --version` will show you which Python installation the default instance of `pip` is installing stuff in. It is probably not the one you expect.

Comment: How are you running python? I'd guess it's from an IDE like PyCharm or VS Code. If so you need to make sure that you are using the correct installation of python that has the PyGame package installed. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467215/2280890) will help.